# Can't charge and use a Li-Po Bluetooth receiver at the same time - can I bypass the battery though?

Tags: battery-charging, usb-device, lipo

I have [this](http://ijetech.com/2030/) Bluetooth receiver. The battery is not holding a lot of charge anymore so it's become pretty useless. I can't plugin the device and use it at the same time, so I was wondering if I could remove the battery and use the cables that originally connected the battery to directly plugin the device. The battery is YJ402025 Li-Po 3.7V 160MAh. USB provides 5V so not sure if that's going to be an issue... I could take pictures of the device's circuit board if that would be helpful.

Comment: Get a new battery instead?

Comment: I'm afraid it will (1) not last much longer than this one and (2) end up being more hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do replace the battery with a USB supply, you should drop the 5 volts down to something closer to 3.7 volts. You could do this with a low drop out 3.5 volt regulator such as the MC33269T  and a small heatsink or you could put two or three 1N400X type diodes in series with the positive lead of the USB supply.

Comment: An LM317 will not work, as the dropout voltage is too high - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214371/lm317-dropout-voltage  There are however adjustable LDOs which will.

Comment: Good point, Chris. I will amend the answer.