# Linear regulator dropping voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a simple component that plays a song when I pull the input pin high. It operates at 3V and everything works fine when I provide power from my bench power supply(I can also see that it draws 0.15A current when operating). I want to build it into a product that has a 5V 2.1A adapter as a power supply so I added an [LM317T](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lm317.pdf) voltage regulator. I configured the regulator with R1=390Ω and R2=560Ω according to *Figure 6*. of the datasheet and when I test the output without load it does provide 3V but when I use it to drive the audio component the output voltage drops to ~2V and the audio is played in a slow and distorted way. At first I just had these two resistors but since then I also added all the recommended capacitors(but not the recommended protection diodes, *Figure 7.*) but it still has the same behavior. According to the datasheet the LM317T should be able to provide 2.2A of current. My questions are: what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Edit: the schematic is the same as Figure 6. Tried to draw it in kicad if it helps(this is the simpler version, I've tried with the caps as well from Figure 7 without the protection diodes): [image]

@Justme: Normal speaker not a piezo(8Ω 0.5w)

@brhans: I took a picture(it's the left regulator): [image]

@audioguru: I'll test that and get back to you but I doubt it, it should be able to provide 2.1A

Took a picture of the component as well, it's from an old alarm clock. The cables are: red=3v, gray: GND, green: input signal(3V), and the two yellow ones are going into the speaker(+/-). [image]

Comment: Show us the schematic.

Comment: What is this simple component and how is it connected to power supplies and speaker? What kind of speaker it is, regular, piezo?

Comment: Does the 5V input to the regulator drop when the regulator output voltage drops?

Comment: In addition to the schematic, show us pics of your actual construction so that we can see if you followed the schematic.

Comment: I've tried to answer all the questions, let me know if you guys need anymore information.

Comment: @Audioguru i've checked and it doesn't drop but it gets a bit noisy on the scope.

Comment: More info: I've found this answer in the meanwhile: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214371/lm317-dropout-voltage so I've checked the datasheet again it says it should be able to provide 0.4A minimum but the current on the chart in Figure 3 does go down to 0 and I have a very small Vi-Vo (~2V) so maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Update: I've tried an LD1117V33 regulator as well and that works fine but I'm a bit concerned because it has a 3.3V output instead of 3V.

Comment: Where does it specify its voltage requirements? Or did you guess based on 2xAA cells or something?

Comment: @erdeszt  Indeed you got the answer all by yourself.   Page 5 of the datasheet shows TYPICAL minimum drop-out voltages.   It's not guaranteed.  And they hover around 2V.  The LM317 is NOT an "LDO" (not a 'low voltage dropout" regulator).  You are asking it to drop less voltage than it's capable of.  It's a VERY old design (40 years?)  Modern LDO's would have NO PROBLEM handling this.  You can easily find one that's "fixed" at 3.0V.  Further, note the LM317 has a MINIMUM output current ... If you're not pulling enough from it, the output floats around.  Modern LDO don't do that either.

Comment: I knew that was your problem just reading your first paragraph.   I was quite happy to see you'd found the solution yourself.   Well done  :)     BTW,  3.3V is a standard "digital" voltage, and PROBABLY would be OK here.  But if you don't KNOW that to be true, you do take some small risk by using it.

Comment: @Finbarr yes it uses 2xAA normally

Comment: Another option, much simplier, is use 3 pieces 1n4148 diode in series.  Each would drop about 0.7V, so you'd get very close to your desired 3V (without needing capacitors).  You'd want to add maybe 1k from 3V to GND, just to make sure there is SOME current flowing in the diodes all the time (keep them at 0.7V drop).   With zero current flowing, they'll not drop quite so much voltage.   SInce you're on a power supply, not batteries, this trickle current shouldn't even be noticed.

Comment: Thanks @KyleB that was very informative, if you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept that. Regarding using a 3.3V regulator or the diodes: I don't feel comfortable with it because I'm trying to fix this clock for a friend and not ruin it, it would probably be really hard replace that chip as the clock is 15+ years old so I'll just use a different regulator.

Comment: HI Brother.   THx for that offer.  I'm not here for the points... just to help my fellow man out.   Good luck!!!!!

Comment: Bear in mind that 1.5V is the nominal voltage for a AA battery, in reality it can be anywhere up to 1.7V or even slightly more [e.g. this one](https://data.energizer.com/PDFs/L91.pdf) - so anything working from two AA cells should be easily able to cope with 3.3V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@erdeszt Indeed you got the answer all by yourself. Page 5 of the datasheet shows TYPICAL minimum drop-out voltages. It's not guaranteed. And they hover around 2V. The LM317 is NOT an "LDO" (not a 'low voltage dropout" regulator). You are asking it to drop less voltage than it's capable of. It's a VERY old design (40 years?) Modern LDO's would have NO PROBLEM handling this. You can easily find one that's "fixed" at 3.0V. Further, note the LM317 has a MINIMUM output current ... If you're not pulling enough from it, the output floats around. Modern LDO don't do that either.

I knew that was your problem just reading your first paragraph. I was quite happy to see you'd found the solution yourself. Well done :) BTW, 3.3V is a standard "digital" voltage, and PROBABLY would be OK here. But if you don't KNOW that to be true, you do take some small risk by using it.